# I am confused about multithreading races?

Tags: multithreading

I was wondering what happens to everything in the withdraw thread? In this picture, both deposit and withdraw are affecting the balance object. I just want to make sure of something,is the stuff on the right stored and if so, when/how does it then appear again. I also want to make sure my vocab is correct... in this case am I creating a race condition?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X00Rb.png)

Answer (score 0):

What is shown in your picture is the "execution sequence" of the operations. So assume you only have one CPU, the CPU first executes two operations from the Deposit thread, switch to the Withdraw thread and execute 4 operations, then switch back to the Deposit thread and execute two more operations.

So this is the answer to your question in the picture "Is all this part gone forever and never used?": At the time represented by the blank area you point to, the Withdraw thread is just idle (or terminated).

Comment: So basically the output would have been the same without that withdraw thread in between?

Comment: It will be the same. And that is the problem because you have done a withdrawing but the balance does not decrease.